# How do I fix the: React is not defined error?

Tags: react-native, package, facebook-sharer

I am running Meteor release METEOR@1.4.2.3

I recently installed a social media share package via Atmosphere.

```
meteor add ellisonleao:sharerjs.
```

You can also read more about it @  http://www.ellison.rocks/sharer.js/
My template looks like this:

```
Template.detail.events({

 "click .sharer": function() {
 //add new buttons with share behaviour

 $('.postedImagesWell').append(<button class="sharer button" data-sharer="facebook" data-url="https://ellisonleao.github.io/sharer.js/">Share on Facebook</button>);                                             
 window.Sharer.init();
        }
});
```

Find below the template in code:

```
<template name="detail">

<div class="postedImagesWell">
  <img class = "img-responsive img-rounded postedImages" id = "trial" src="{{this.photo.url}}" alt="thumbnail" >

</template>
```

when I run click on the `Share on Facebook` link. I see this error message in my browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

I have done some research on how to resolve the following issue which resulted in having to install various packages, which have shown to be all futile. I have had to uninstalled the packages.

Any help on how to resolve the issue would be great!

Comment: Are you sure React in installed and correctly imported?

Comment: @ Mikael am not sure, how do I check if it's installed?

Comment: @Mikael  I run `meteor list` and it shows:  `react-meteor-data` & `reactive-var`. At the top of my client/main.js I have: `import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';` & `import React from 'react';` my browser console doesn't indicate any error messages.

Comment: @Mikael I am noticing that the error message isnt showing `React is not defined error?` anymore, its now showing: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined`